# Laravel download view as pdf with images

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I am using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package to download view as a pdf. In the page I have put some images with internal links. Internal links are protected with auth and some other middleware. When I see the view all images are there, but after downloading the pdf, images are not being loaded (Shows message:  Image not found or type unknown) due to auth middleware.

What can be the alternative ways to download pdf with images.

I can't remove middleware from the image url.

Comment: You can authenticate package in its service provider.

Comment: You can encode the images as base64 in the view also. Maybe there is a cleaner solution though!

Comment: @MartinVandersteen Yeah, I converted the images in the controller and then converted as base64 image and sent it the the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did,
I fetched the images in the controller itself and then converted the images as base64 image. And then passed to the view. Now everything is working fine.